# How to use two cursors for writing in single file?

Tags: plsql

Suppose In my procedure, there are two cursors and I have a requirement of writing from both the cursors, 1st line from 1st cursor and 2nd line from 2nd cursor and so on..
How do i achieve it??? I know how to fetch from single curs
or.
Or there is some other way.
Thanks in Advance,

Nitika

Answer (score 0):

You could use two [for loop](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/cursor_for.php) statements, like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure aProc(filter IN number) IS

cursor c1 is select something, something_else from myTable where something = filter;
cursor c2 is select something2, something_else2 from myTable2;

begin
     for alias1 in c1 loop
         for alias2 in c2 loop
             if(alias1.something = 1) then
                insert into myTable3 (value1,value2,value3)
                            values (alias1.something_else,
                                    alias2.something2,
                                    alias2.something_else2);
             end if;
         end loop;
     end loop;
end;
```

The for loop statement will close the open cursors when no more data is found.